# Entering the user's name in a URL for Chrome through Group Policy

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, google-chrome

I am managing a Windows Server 2008 R2 server, with several Windows 7 machines, and we have recently deployed Google Chrome using Group Policy. We also have a locally hosted intranet for storing procedures, forms, and so on, as well as reports that pull directly from our databases.

I am trying to put the user's name in the startup URL for Chrome, so that when they open Chrome at the beginning of the day, it can pull a list of items from the database that contains their username. The report works, and I have it using a drop down right now, but I would like to be able to put their username in the URL as a GET variable instead. Does anybody know how I would go about doing that for Chrome? I tried putting ${user_name} in the URL, and I tried putting %username% in the URL, but that didn't translate to anything. Is there some way to escape it so that it gets translated by the system into a username? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of trying to get Group Policy to configure the browser to identify the user to the web server wouldn't it be better to get the web server to identify the user by their Windows username (using Integrated Windows Authentication on the web site)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could launch Chrome from a batch file using something like:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" intranet/%username%

This will populate the logged in username to the URL.

I agree with the other comment that getting the username from Windows Integrated Authentication is probably a better option (and more secure if you are going to rely on this username for any sort of authentication).